# Change app page order

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 running Jelly Bean.
I have sorted my apps in pages, by topic or whatever (not the home screens, but the app/widget pages). Now I would like to sort those pages, but I can't find the way to change the order of the pages. Can it be done? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found it! Pinch with two fingers on the Home Page, to enter the edit pages mode, then move them around.

Comment: SWIPE with too fingers where ?

Comment: Edited content to make the Swipe a Pinch.

Comment: @wbogacz It certainly works with a pinch, but also with a two finger swipe (works better with a vertical swipe).